# phpunit mock - method does not exist

Tags: php, unit-testing, cakephp, phpunit, cakephp-3.0

I recently updated PHPunit from 5.3 to 5.5 in an IntegrationTestCase of an app that is CakePhp 3.x based. and I don't understand how to update my mock generation scripts.

Originally I created my mock like this:

```
$stub = $this->getMock('SomeClass', array('execute'));
$stub->method('execute')
     ->will($this->returnValue($this->returnUrl));
```

After the change to PHPUnit 5.5 this got me the following warning:

```
PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase::getMock() is deprecated,
use PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase::createMock()
or PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase::getMockBuilder() instead
```

In order to fix this warning I changed the mock-generation to:

````
$stub = $this->getMockBuilder('SomeClass', array('execute'))->getMock();
$stub->method('execute')
     ->will($this->returnValue($this->returnUrl));```
````

Now I get the following error message when running the test:

```
exception 'PHPUnit_Framework_MockObject_RuntimeException' 
with message 'Trying to configure method "execute" which cannot be
configured because it does not exist, has not been specified, 
is final, or is static'
```

Anybody know, how to avoid this error? Thank you.

Comment: can you post the code of the `execute` method?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

`PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase::getMockBuilder()` only takes one (1) argument, the class name. The methods to mock are ment to be defined via the returned mock builder objects `setMethods()` method.

```
$stub = $this
    ->getMockBuilder('SomeClass')
    ->setMethods(['execute'])
    ->getMock();
```

See also

- **[PHPUnit Manual > Test Doubles > Mock Objects](https://phpunit.de/manual/5.5/en/test-doubles.html#test-doubles.mock-objects)**

Comment: Thanks, that's it. I should have used setMethods instead of trying to pass an array of method-names as a second-parameter in the getMockBuilder()-method.

Comment: FYI, setMethods() is deprecated and should be replaced with onlyMethods()

Comment: @GordonM That is correct, but CakePHP 3.x by default requires PHPUnit 6.x at the latest, where `onlyMethods()` doesn't exist yet. I'm not sure if 3.x is even compatible with PhpUnit 8+ 

Answer (score 21):

I will leave this as an answer to myself, when i reach this problem again:

**The mocked method may not be private.**

Answer (score 2):

First of all, it's just

```
$stub = $this->getMockBuilder('SomeClass')->getMock();
```

Second, error states that method `execute` does exist in your class `SomeClass`.

So, check if it really exists and it's `public` and not `final`.

If everything's good, check a full classname, if it real and specified with correct namespace.

To avoid stupid errors with classname, it's better to use this syntax:

```
$stub = $this->getMockBuilder(SomeClass::class)->getMock();
```

In this case, if SomeClass doesn't exist or namespace is missed, you will get a clear error about it.

Comment: Thanks, the problem was that I did not use the setMethods() function (see ndm's answer).

Comment: It's not required step though. Do you have this method in original class?

Comment: Yes, I have it in my original class and my test expects "execute" to be called (see code example in my question).

Comment: @DmitryMalyshenko It is required in case the method isn't public.

Comment: if it's not public, how can tested class use it?

Comment: The same way as any other method that lives in its scope, it can just call it.

Comment: But it's not a tested class, it's another class, it's dependency. It's not same scope

Comment: It's an extending class, yes, but for protected methods its still the same scope. It wouldn't be for private methods, but those cannot be mocked in the first place.

Comment: And yes, I know that in an ideal world you'd only test the public API :)

Comment: Who said it's extending class? As I see use of a mocker: `$dep = new AClass; $b = new BClass($dep)` . When you test class BClass, you need to mock class AClass. But anyway $b cannot use private (or protected, no matter) methods of $dep.

Comment: I said, because that's how mocks work, they extend the original class. Your example has nothing to with either how mocks work, or with the OPs code, so I don't really know what you are trying to say?

Comment: I am trying to say, that either method exists and it's public, and then `setMethods` not needed, or it doesn't make any sense to make a mocker at all.

Comment: That would only be true if the class would never call any of its public methods itself, or when you'd create expectations for _all_ these public methods, as not restricting the methods via `setMethods()` would cause _all_ public methods to be mocked. You can't really generalize and say it doesn't make sense, because we don't live in this perfect world where everyone encapsulates their public APIs in a way that internals never access it, and even then there may still be valid use cases for mocking a protected method.

Comment: Anyways, this is a discussion about programming concepts now, and has nothing do with the OPs problem anymore, which is that he needed to use `setMethods()` because obviously the method wasn't public. So I'd say let's stop it as this point :)

Answer (score 2):

Addition to upper messages: split mock method declarations

Instead of this:

```
$mock
    ->method('persist')
       ->with($this->isInstanceOf(Bucket::class))
       ->willReturnSelf()
    ->method('save')
       ->willReturnSelf()
;
```

Use this:

```
$mock
    ->method('persist')
        ->willReturnSelf()
;

$mock
   ->method('save')
       ->willReturnSelf()
;
```

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps , the method does not exist in the class that you mock .

Comment: The method was missing on the mock (see the accepted anwer by ndm and my comment for solution)

Comment: i was facing the same issue , and then i find that my class does not contain the method , so i'm proposing this solution to resolve the same problem somehow .

Comment: Got it, might help somebody else